# At what level should i check for record existence in Microservices?

Tags: microservices

Imagine I have two services A and B, and one of the entities of A has a relation with some entity in B. Where should I place the checking logic?

I considered two options

1. Use Ocelot API Gateway to check for Record existence before inserting
2. Use async messaging where I insert the record and add a consistency flag at service A. Service A will publish an event: CheckExistanceEvent and listen to the event: RecordExistEvent published by B

I think both of my solutions are bad and introduce coupling. I have looked for solutions but nothing was clear to me.

Any suggestion on where I should check for record existence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach that will minimize coupling is for service B to publish events on creation (and deletion, if that exists) of its entities.  Then any service (such as A) which needs to know whether a given entity owned by B exists can maintain its own view of which entities exist, regardless of whether B is up or not.

Comment: Wouldn't this bloat the message queue? Or should I use a temp store like Redis to store the events? Or should I add a redundant table on A service to store entities coming from CreateEvent

Comment: Re: bloat, the number of messages is 1 or at most 2 (if deletion is involved) per entity.  For option 2, the message queue is going to be bloated by at least 2 messages per entity in A (the extra being `CheckExistence`s that don't get a reply: if B goes down, the failure can now cascade to taking down the message queue).  So if you're considering option 2, this approach is strictly better.

Comment: How A stores its view of which entities exist can be based solely on what A's requirements are (availability, scalability, durability, ...).  It might mean a table in A.  It might mean a service with the sole purpose of answering "does this entity exist" (which would allow your option 1 design for use cases where that's OK; note that that simple of a service is likely to not need maintenance and will probably be somewhat more available than B).